# gazebo_gui-3 error when starting gazebo with roslaunch

Tags: ros, gazebo-1.9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hey

I have this problem that's happening more often the whole last week when starting gazebo using roslaunch, I haven't installed any updates though.
Is there any permanent solution for it because it so annoying not to start gazebo right away and it works only after 5 to 6 times attempts

The system: gazebo 1.9.1, groovy, gazebo_ros_package

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[gazebo_gui-3] process has died [pid 16577, exit code 139, cmd /home/zahraa/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros/scripts/gzclient __name:=gazebo_gui __log:=/home/zahraa/.ros/log/4139ed3a-13e2-11e3-9765-6c626d02622d/gazebo_gui-3.log].
log file: /home/zahraa/.ros/log/4139ed3a-13e2-11e3-9765-6c626d02622d/gazebo_gui-3*.log
```

I tried to find the error by going to  4139ed3a-13e2-11e3-9765-6c626d02622d
but this directory doesn't not have `gazebo_gui-3*.log`  file and  it has other log files such as spawn_urdf.log and master.log etc..

thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4252/gazebo_gui-3-error-when-starting-gazebo-with-roslaunch/) by [Zahra](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/320/zahra/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 122 on 2013-09-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

solved by starting gazebo client in another terminal after sourcing  . ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash

and rosrun gazebo_ros gzclient

---

Originally posted by [Zahra](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/320/zahra/) with karma: 122 on 2013-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bimblis](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2749/bimblis/) on 2016-08-04**:
Newie here, could you elaborate in what you needed to do?

**Comment by [desmond13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8998/desmond13/) on 2020-07-08**:
This did not work for me :(

**Comment by [desmond13](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8998/desmond13/) on 2020-11-25**:
Anyone has more info on this problem? I have it again now.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The problem is that roslaunch secretly adds two arguments when starting a node's executable: `__name` and `__log`.  If the node's executable is not ROS interoperable, then the executable may fail because it doesn't know how to handle the __name and __log arguments that were added on by roslaunch.  This is the case here, since roslaunch is calling the "gzclient" script, which executes "gzclient" with arguments passed in by roslaunch.  gzclient dies because it doesn't know how to handle the __name and __log arguments passed in from roslaunch.

The workaround you found works because it uses rosrun to start the gzclient instead of roslaunch.  rosrun doesn't add those pesky "__name" and "__log" parameters.

---

Originally posted by [pcdangio](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/257/pcdangio/) with karma: 207 on 2016-02-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yah130s](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1228/yah130s/) on 2016-07-23**:
+1 for raising attention to those 2 options. I still have the same question as the one I made at [this post](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4153/gazebo-crashes-immediately-using-roslaunch-after-installing-gazebo-ros-packages/?answer=12620#post-id-12620).